# Test if process is running on remote units and output to log

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, remote-server, tasklist

We would like to check if a certain process is running on any of our listed servers, outputting the result to a log file like this:

```
SERVERNAME Process is running
SERVERNAME Process is not running
```

I'm new to batch but this is how far I got:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN (LIST.TXT) DO TASKLIST /S %%A /FI "IMAGENAME EQ IEXPLORE.EXE" >> ECHO %%A D:\SEARCH.LOG
```

Comment: you are pretty much there, however you are piping to echo. I suspect you only want to see the output and the name of the device it came from.

Comment: Yes indeed the piping I don't know how to do it. I guess I have to use IF ERRORLEVEL?

Comment: no, see my answer below, it lists each instance per device

Comment: @KevinQuasten, you do know that I posted my answer which does exactly what you asked before Gerhard, and certainly before his edits, made it more like mine. Is there a reason why you've ignored my answer completely?

Comment: @Compo, I tried the command but it didn't work for me. Gerhard post did work for me. Sorry

Comment: Check `tasklist`,`qprocess` and `wmic process` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should pretty much do what you want.

```
  @echo off
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   for /F "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
     tasklist /s %%a | find /I "iexplore.exe" >nul
      if !errorlevel! equ 0 (echo %%a Process is Running) else (echo %%a Process is Not Running)
 ) >> d:\search.log
```

As for your requirement on RPC errors, perhaps consider `rpcping` and echo to file if not available.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
    rpcping -s %%a |find /i "Completed" >nul
    if not !errorlevel! equ 0 echo %%a RPC Server not available
    tasklist /s %%a | find /I "iexplore.exe" >nul
    if !errorlevel! equ 0 (echo %%a Process is Running) else (echo %%a Process is Not Running)
 ) >> d:\search.log
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but i don't need the full output of the command only the server name followed by "is running" or "is not running"

Comment: Great Gerhard working perfect now. There is 1 more issue: Some server s don't have the RPC enabled so it can't execute it remotely. Is there any way to log that too? It does an ECHO in the CMD window like this: Fout: De RPC-server is niet beschikbaar.

Comment: Gerhard, the identifier will echo all errors as "Process is not running"  to the log file no?

Comment: @KevinQuasten no, only for errorlevel on the `find /I` function. Remember the first code? Those actually piped all output to the file.

Comment: can you please help me with that? I really don't know where to place that echo for other failures :(

Comment: Ok, but I would like to separate the two. If the RPC server is not available it's possible the server still has the process running. So we need to RDP to the server and check manually. Actually, it's not iexplore we are checking for but a backup application which we don't want to be running anymore. We pay per server and we have veaam instead on vm's.

Comment: @Gerard for some reason it's not looping through the list after your last edit. It just closes without echo anything anymore

Comment: maybe you do not have rpcping? can you try from cmdline `rpcping /?`

Comment: I commented the rpcping

Comment: try now please?

Comment: The script is working but it's duplicating the results if rpc service is not available. It also show process is not running. We have 700+ server to process so it would be nice if we don't have to filter them manualy.

Answer (score 0):

What you have, isn't far away, to get the output you asked for however, you could change your script more like this:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
(FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN (LIST.TXT
    ) DO TASKLIST /S %%A|FIND /I "IEXPLORE.EXE">NUL&&(Echo %%A Process is running
    )||Echo %%A Process is not running)>D:\SEARCH.LOG
```

Comment: This produces error `'server01' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` You need to add `echo` before `%%A Process...`